# How to change endpoint for HTTP callout to an apex rest endpoint?

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, apexrest

I have an external endpoint that is being called from one of my sandboxes. I will not be able to use the endpoint in the new sandbox due to limitation on the external endpoint that prevents additional sandboxes from accessing the endpoint for security reasons. Instead, I need to simulate the request such that we modify the callout endpoint to be an apex rest endpoint URL so we can mock the response.

**Question(s):**

1. How can we set the external endpoint to now be an apex endpoint url to mock requests?

**What exists now:**

```
trigger MyAccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
  List<String> acntNames = new List<String>();
  for(Account acnt : Trigger.new) {
    acntNames.add(acnt.Name);
  }
  String reqBody = JSON.serialize(acntName);

  Http httpTest = new Http();
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  MyCustomMetadata__c myMetadata = [select name,URL__c from MyCustomMetadata__c limit 1];
  req.setEndpoint(myMetadata.URL__c);
  req.setBody(reqBody);
  HttpResponse httpRes = httpTest.send(req);
}
```

**what we tried but got the following errors**

1. changed `MyCustomMetadata__c` record where Name='MyEndPoint' such that `MyCustomMetadata__c.URL__c` is changed from `https://external-endpoint.com` to `https://mysandbox.url.com`
2. Made no changes to trigger code

**Error message:**

> {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Comment: It is not possible to make a synchronous callout from a trigger. Is the 'what exists now' just a grossly simplified example?

Comment: @MarkPond there is a lot more that gets added to the request body from the account records but I removed a lot of that to provide a simple example. The remainder in terms of `httprequest` and `HttpResponse` is the implementation

Comment: Can you simulate the API using a service like Mockaroo and just change the value in your custom metadata record field?

Comment: @identigral no the `HttpCallOutMock` has a `respond()` method but that is used in `Test.startTest()`, which not in the picture here

Comment: @identigral if only the requirements could be easily changed. `Test.startTest()` is not applicable here

Comment: @MarkPond not able to simulate the API in Mockaroo

Comment: why not refactor so the callout is done via a class that is dependency-injected at runtime based on the value of some custom metadata field whose value is sandbox-specific?

Comment: @cropredy we did create one to store the `URL__c` per sandbox but it results in error message from the post

Comment: your code doesn't look like it is [passing the sessionId in the header](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099zbIAA)